# How to stop MKMapView from being called right away

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I have a `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` delegate method that is called at the beginning of the app when MKMapView is loaded. How can I stop it from being called right away? I don't mind it being called when user drags the map, but just not when mapview is loaded.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
```

Comment: Why does it matter if this is called upon initialization of the MKMapView? Is there something happening in your implementation of `mapView: regionDidChangeAnimated:` that you don't want to happen on the initial call?

Comment: To put it another way: If a delegate method is called and you don't want to do anything, don't do anything. Or: don't set the delegate until after the map view is loaded.